# Atualizar um app sem Google Play

Tags: android, atualização

1. Acabei de fechar uma versão beta de um app Android que não pode ser distribuído na google play.
2. Vou disponibilizar um link especial para alguns usuários baixarem. É muito importante que isso fique fora da loja/beta program do android.
3. Todos esses usuários tem acesso *root* no seu dispositivo

Qual seria a melhor forma de enviar atualizações para esse app dinamicamente, sem que eu tenha que gerar um novo link?

Comment: você já tentou alguma coisa?